# ¿Cómo se en que posiciones esta un elemento de una lista?

Tags: python, lista

Genera 100 números aleatorios entre 1 y 50
y guárdalos en una lista. Busca el número 37
dentro de él e indica en qué posición está (si no
está, indícalo):

```
#Genero una lista de 100 numeros random entre 1 y 50

import random
lista = []
for i in range(1,100):
 lista = lista + [random.randint(30,40)]

#Visualizar

print(lista)
print(37 in lista)
print(lista.count(37))

#Intento ver en que posiciones esta el 37

for a in lista:
    if a == 37:
        print(f'El numero 37 esta en la posición {lista.index(a)}')
        
else:
    print("El numero 37 no está")
```

Solo me sale la primera posicion en la que está el 37 pero no salen las demás.

Comment: eso ocurre por que el método `index` solo devuelve la primera posicion del elemento

Comment: Se me ocurre hacer `for a,i in zip(lista,range(len(lista))):` y poner `i` en el print, así `print(f'El numero 37 esta en la posición {i}')`

Comment: @Christian o usando la función enumerate `for i, a in enumerate(lista)`

Answer (score 0):

Solución:

```
# Genero una lista de 100 numeros random entre 1 y 50

import random

lista = [random.randint(30, 40) for _ in range(100)]

encontrados = 0
for i in range(len(lista)):
    if lista[i] == 37:
        print("lista[{}] = {}".format(i, lista[i]))
        encontrados += 1

print("{} valores encontrados".format(encontrados))
```

Para generar la lista de 100 números aleatorios usamos comprensión de listas, que es más corto:

```
lista = [random.randint(30, 40) for _ in range(100)]
```

Notese que uso `_` como indice para indicar que no me interesa usar su valor. No es necesario para formar la lista.

Luego recorro la lista variando el índice de la lista. En cada iteración comparo el valor en la posición y lo imprimo si es el deseado.

```
for i in range(len(lista)):
    if lista[i] == 37:
        print("lista[{}] = {}".format(i, lista[i]))
        encontrados += 1
```

Como llevo la cuenta en `encontrados`, al final puedo saber si encontre alguno o no.

#### Demo

```
# Genero una lista de 100 numeros random entre 1 y 50
import random

lista = [random.randint(30, 40) for _ in range(100)]

encontrados = 0
for i in range(len(lista)):
    if lista[i] == 37:
        print("lista[{}] = {}".format(i, lista[i]))
        encontrados += 1

print("{} valores encontrados".format(encontrados))
for i in range(0, 100, 10):
    print(lista[i:i+10])
```

produce:

```
lista[4] = 37
lista[5] = 37
lista[8] = 37
lista[11] = 37
lista[23] = 37
lista[24] = 37
lista[34] = 37
lista[36] = 37
lista[40] = 37
lista[74] = 37
10 valores encontrados
[33, 30, 30, 32, 37, 37, 34, 34, 37, 38]
[33, 37, 32, 33, 33, 33, 38, 31, 38, 33]
[34, 36, 38, 37, 37, 34, 39, 31, 40, 39]
[34, 30, 39, 32, 37, 35, 37, 40, 35, 32]
[37, 35, 34, 40, 40, 31, 31, 30, 31, 33]
[30, 36, 30, 32, 38, 32, 32, 38, 35, 33]
[30, 32, 35, 34, 34, 36, 35, 32, 33, 40]
[39, 30, 32, 35, 37, 34, 34, 34, 33, 34]
[34, 40, 33, 36, 38, 39, 35, 38, 34, 36]
[32, 31, 32, 38, 40, 34, 40, 31, 33, 40]

Process finished with exit code 0
```